# C program to show is input is int or char?

Tags: c++

I want this code to output a string "integer" if user enters int data type, and "character" if he enters char data type.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

main()
{
   int x;
   char x;
   cin>>x;
   if(input is integer)
   { 
       cout<<"You have entered integer."<<endl;
   }
   else{
      cout<<"You have entered character."<<endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: Both `int` and `char` are integral types. Mixing `c` and `c++` tags in a question is better avoided. Please start with the [help]. Welcome to SO.

Comment: Input into a `std::string` and then parse it to your liking. C or C++?!

Comment: A `char` is an integer, as is `int`. They (usually) have different range and it's implementation defined if `char` is signed or not, but they both hold integer numbers and what can be put into a `char` can also be put into a `int`. So, if the user enters something that can fit in both you can't really say it's of one type or the other - both will do.

Comment: Input is neither `int` nor `char`; it is merely **text**. In order to determine whether the text that the user typed can be converted to an integer, you can either scan it for any non-digit characters, or try to convert it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly `C` and `C++` are similar but very different languages. So please use either `C` tag or `C++`.

As for the question:

You can use [generic selection](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic) from C11.

This is the syntax

```
 _Generic ( controlling-expression , association-list )
```

it performs lvalue conversions on `controlling-expression`.

So you can define a macro function `get_type()`

```
#define get_type(expr)                \
        _Generic((expr),              \
                    int: "int",       \
                   char: "char",      \
                 double: "double"     \
                )
```

Then you can use it like this

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define get_type(expr)                \
        _Generic((expr),              \
                    int: "int",       \
                   char: "char",      \
                 double: "double"     \
                )



int main()
{

    int a = 0;
    char b = 'b';

    printf("%s\n", get_type(a));
    printf("%s\n", get_type(b));

    if(strcmp("int", get_type(a)) == 0)
    {
        printf("a is an int\n");
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Output will be

```
int
char
a is an int
```

Now you can do comparison on input type!

I'll leave how to do that up to you.